# get date by feeding week of the year to moment.js

Tags: momentjs

is there a way to get date by feeding week of the year to moment.js?

I want something like this:

```
moment(moment.setWeek(2));
```

by doing so I expect to get date when week 2 was started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer:

```
moment(moment().week(2));
```